# Skyrim Crashing right after exiting Ironbind barrow

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

my game keeps crashing right after exiting this cave after opening the locked gate to get out (the exit door) as i appear at the wooden door that has a board locking it closed the game crashed. i looked in its log last thing it said was Texture 2738. then nothing. i tried another loging approach that adds a log folder. the folder appeared but nothing else in side it.

i dont know or y its causing it on my pc but its really starting to make me madder then a bull

i tryed it once more with the logging process and it claims it was detecting a crash and it shut down the game.. O-o

Comment: Are you using any mods?

Comment: yes i am. -_- close to max. xD but b4 this the game was running fine on the outside areas. mostly armor mods along with HD textures

Comment: Does uninstalling / disabling the mods impact on the occurrence of the issue?

Comment: i tryed the HD texture mods (im runing the highest gpu card i could get 2  yrs ago so i know it hand handle the HD textures. ) but from what i looked at in the log its trying to load a 250 (i think) texture and thats when it starts to crash. i unloaded the HD mod and i got the same logging  (i used a spell to spawn him into riften no crashing. i think it might have to do something with exiting that cave. i might be wrong. i wish i had more detail in what is causing this crash..

Answer (score 1):

I often get crashing on level transition in skyrim. It will repeatedly crash on making the same level transition.
The solution I have found is to advance time by pressing the button "T" and then enter.
Even advancing one single hour is usually enough to allow me to make the other crashy transition without problem

Answer (score 0):

As much as it will be a pain, try disabling the last mod you downloaded, if it doesn't work, try all mods 1 by 1 and see if that works.

By the sounds of it that is a Texture problem.

Theres all sorts of mods like flying ships, as you would exit the burrow, are there any 'non-vanilla' objects visible from the entrance? Try disabling the mod that would show that.

Try disabling all mods. Just dont save as you would loose your modded weapons.

Its obviously not crashing in the burrow mainly because probably **none** of you mods affect that cell at all. But obviously outside wont load.

Good luck.